# execute NextJS middleware when no page path match

Tags: next.js, middleware

I have a NextJS application with the following pages.

/

/page1

/page2/:id

/page3

I want to write a middleware matcher function (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matcher) so that the middleware will only execute when none of the page paths mentioned above matches.

Comment: can you provide your code? also this can be done easily in next.config.js why do you need a middleware?

Comment: If a path does not match any path in my /pages directory. I need to execute an API in the middleware to figure out if a redirect to another URL is needed. The next.config approach does not work for me because the redirects are changing all the time & re-running the build when that change happens is not possible.